# How can I permanently delete an object from core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm building an app that uses data to hold objects and then fetching the results to store them in an array, which is displayed in a table view. I have added a function so that users can delete a row from the table view, I've also made it so that it deletes the object from core data. It works to a certain extent, when I test it on the simulator the row gets deleted (it doesn't crash) and I can navigate to other view controllers and come back to the table view afterwards... the row I deleted seems to have been deleted from core data. The problem comes when I stop the simulator and then re-start it again. I go back to the table view and the row I deleted appears again, as if it was still in memory. Being a new programmer I'm not sure if it is a problem with the simulator, and that it would work as desired on an actual device, or if my code doesn't work. Can someone more experienced tell me if it's a simulator problem or if I'm doing something wrong, cheers guys and gals!

```
var myList: Array<AnyObject> = []

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ToDoList")        

    myList = context.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)!
}


//This is where I think something is going wrong
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let appDeleg: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let contexts: NSManagedObjectContext = appDeleg.managedObjectContext!

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

        if let tblview = self.tableView {

            contexts.deleteObject(myList[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
            myList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tblview.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are saving your `NSManagedObjectContext` at some point with `contexts.save()` otherwise your changes will not persist in between app launches. You can perform your save in `applicationDidEnterBackground` or in some cases within your application logic. Since saving can be an expensive operation, check `hasChanges` beforehand. Apple Documentation says:

> Always verify that the context has uncommitted changes (using the hasChanges property) before invoking the save: method. Otherwise, Core Data may perform unnecessary work.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. I did the following: contexts.save(nil) in the delete function... which is temporary until I read the documentation and fix the problem the way you told me to. Again thanks a lot.